# How does setting the opt argument for lmeControl change estimation?

Tags: r, multi-level, nlme

I'm wondering if anyone knows how exactly setting the optimizer in lme() to opt='optim' changes parameter estimation.

As in this example:

```
ctrl <- lmeControl(opt='optim');
flow.lme <- lme(rate ~ nozzle, error= nozzle|operator, control=ctrl, data=Flow)
```

A related question was posed and answered here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/lme-error-iteration-limit-reached) but I don't have the reputation points to comment on it. : )

Answer (score 3):

From `?lmeControl`:

> opt: the optimizer to be used, either ‘"nlminb"’ (the default) or
>             ‘"optim"’.
>
> optimMethod: character - the optimization method to be used with the
>             ‘optim’ optimizer.  The default is ‘"BFGS"’.  An alternative
>             is ‘"L-BFGS-B"’.

As part of the estimation process, `lme` has to use a nonlinear optimization function to estimate the variance-covariance parameters.  `nlminb()` and `optim()` are the two main built-in optimizers in R: while `nlminb` uses a single underlying algorithm, `optim` gives a choice of algorithms.

It's rather difficult to know *a priori* which nonlinear optimization function will work best on a particular set of data.